# double pointer in struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I have a struct like this

```
struct Example
{
    int a;
    int ** b;
}
```

and I want to call malloc in such way that I can then have b[][], a double array of ints.
I do it like this after declaring the struct under the name example in my main

```
*example.b = malloc(x);
example.b = malloc(y);
```

where x and y are defined and assigned unsigned ints.

Doing that gives me segfaults.
How do I get a double array out of such double pointer?

Answer (score 0):

At first you want memory for `x` pointers and then you want each of those pointers to point to  memory block big enough to hold `y` integers:

```
int i = 0;
example.b = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    example.b[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
```

and don't forget that for every `malloc` a `free` must be called to free this memory:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    free(example.b[i]);
free(example.b);
```

Comment: Why do I need to malloc every element of the 1st dimension? I recently tried to swap around my code so that I do

    example.b = malloc(x);
    *example.b = malloc(y);
and that works okay, and frees in the same order work okay.

Answer (score 0):

To allocate memory that corresponds to `int[nrows][ncols]` you can do something like the following:

```
int i, nrows, ncols;
struct Example str;

str.b = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*(str.b)));
if (str.b==NULL)
    printf("Error: memory allocation failed\n");

for (i=0; i<nrows; ++i) {
    str.b[i] = malloc(ncols * sizeof(*(str.b[i])));
    if (str.b[i]==NULL)
        printf("Error: memory allocation failed\n");
}
```